# C++LSP - ILanguageClient -Connector not loading in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, language-server-protocol

**I try to implement a language client with ILanguageClient in C#**

- as I launch the project and open a cpp file, **nothing kicks in**
- **breakpoints are disabled**

I tried:

Added a config file to **enable the trace**, nothing happens either, **no log gets created**

in the .vs folder, I created **VSWorkspaceSettings.json**

it contains:

```
{
   "c_cpp.trace.server": "Verbose"
}
```

I follow the **instructions** from **microsoft**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2019

**Any help appreciated on making this work**

here is the code

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClangdLSPConnector
{
    public class BarContentDefinition
    {
        [Export]
        [Name("c_cpp")]
        [BaseDefinition(CodeRemoteContentDefinition.CodeRemoteContentTypeName)]
        internal static ContentTypeDefinition BarContentTypeDefinition;

        [Export]
        [FileExtension(".cpp")]
        [ContentType("c_cpp")]
        internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition BarFileExtensionDefinitionCpp;

        [Export]
        [FileExtension(".h")]
        [ContentType("c_cpp")]
        internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition BarFileExtensionDefinitionH;
    }

    [ContentType("c_cpp")]
    [Export(typeof(ILanguageClient))]
    class LSPLanguageClient : ILanguageClient
    {
        public string Name => "C/C++ Language Extension";

        public IEnumerable<string> ConfigurationSections => null;

        public object InitializationOptions => null;

        public IEnumerable<string> FilesToWatch => null;

        public bool ShowNotificationOnInitializeFailed => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> StartAsync;
        public event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> StopAsync;

        event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> ILanguageClient.StartAsync
        {
            add
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            remove
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> ILanguageClient.StopAsync
        {
            add
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            remove
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public async Task<Connection> ActivateAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = "C:\\my\\path\\to\\server\\bin\\clangd.exe";
            info.Arguments = "";
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = info;

            if (process.Start())
            {
                return new Connection(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream, process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public async Task OnLoadedAsync()
        {
            await StartAsync.InvokeAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public Task OnServerInitializeFailedAsync(Exception e)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task OnServerInitializedAsync()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task<InitializationFailureContext> OnServerInitializeFailedAsync(ILanguageClientInitializationInfo initializationState)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone else tried this ? could the doc be wrong ?